# React Native WebView Permissions

Tags: react-native

I put a website in a webview in react native, the website has a permission in using the camera and audio but the issue is, the permission prompt is not showing in the mobile app, i also tried to enable all the permissions of the app, but still i can't record audio/video. what will be the solution for this?

Comment: Check if you have the permissions set as in this page https://reactnative.dev/docs/permissionsandroid

Comment: "i also tried to enable all the permissions of the app," How did you try doing this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `PermissionsAndroid` of React-native to ask for permissions

Following is the code for asking permissions :

```
async checkPermissions() {    
 await PermissionsAndroid.requestMultiple([
  PermissionsAndroid.PERMISSIONS.CAMERA,
 ]).then(result => {
  console.log('checkPermissions result', result);        
 });
}
```

Provide whatever permissions you require in the array and check for their status in result.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using expo, first install:

```
expo install expo-camera
```

Then, in your WebView:

```
import { Camera } from "expo-camera";

export default function MyWebView({ route }) {
  Camera.requestCameraPermissionsAsync();
  ... your webViewCode ... 
}
```

source: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/camera/#camerarequestcamerapermissionsasync